# How to get the first child of td attribute on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

How to get the first child of the td on HOVER of the following and display the value of the attribute "templateid" that is equal to 1 or 2 depending on which is on hover. For example if I hover on templateid = 2 input. I will get the following value 2

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td><input class="form-group form-control" type="checkbox" templateid="1"> </td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td input class="form-group form-control" type="checkbox" templateid="2"></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
  </tr> 
</tbody>
```

Comment: `$("#tableid").find("td :checkbox:nth-child(1)").attr("templateid")`

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$("#tableid").hover(function(){
    var getfirstchildTD = $(this).find("td :checkbox:nth-child(1)").attr("templateid");
    alert(getfirstchildTD);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you want, but I hope this is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //when hover on checkbox
    $('tbody').on('mouseenter','input:checkbox',function() {
         //get templateid attribute value of the checkbox which is placed at first <td> in <tr> 
         var yea = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first input:checkbox').attr('templateid');
         alert(yea);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working solution please try it

```js
$("input").hover(function(){
    var getfirstchildTD = $(this).attr("templateid");
    alert(getfirstchildTD);
})
```

```html
    <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td><input class="form-group form-control" type="checkbox" templateid="1"> </td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td><input class="form-group form-control" type="checkbox" templateid="2"></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
          </tr> 
</tbody>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `jQuery`[:first-child](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```
$("td:first-child input:first-child").hover(function(){
    var templateid = $(this).attr("templateid");
    //TODO your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('hello');
$('#table tbody tr td:first-child').on('mouseover', function() {
    
    console.log($(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('templateid'));
  })
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>h1</th>
      <th>h2</th>
      <th>h3</th>
      <th>h4</th>
      <th>h5</th>
      <th>h5</th>
      <th>h7</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-group form-control" type="checkbox" templateid="1">something </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-group form-control" type="checkbox" templateid="2">something</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```